# Where is the help.py for Android's monkeyrunner

Tags: android, python, testing, monkeyrunner

I just can't find the `help.py` file in order to create the API reference for the `monkeyrunner`. The command described at the [Android references](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html#Help)

`monkeyrunner <format> help.py <outfile>` does not work when i call `monkeyrunner html help.py /path/to/place/the/doc.html`.

It's quite obvious that the `help.py` file is not found and the monkeyrunner also tells me "Can't open specified script file". But a `locate` on my system doesn't bring me a help.py file that has anything to do with monkeyrunner or Android.

So my question is: Where did they hide the help.py file for creating the API reference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I cannot find it either. But one can assume that it is simply calling MonkeyRunner.help() with the passed in arguments. If you just want to get something quick use this script I created also named **help.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

text = MonkeyRunner.help("html");

f = open('help.html', 'w')
f.write(text);
f.close();
```

Run it just like any other monkeyrunner script:

```
$ monkeyrunner help.py
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. throwing exception when executing the fourth line (when executing help method).

Answer (score 1):

http://androidxref.com/source/xref/sdk/monkeyrunner/scripts/help.py

I believe the documentation on the website starts from that script, but I'm pretty sure somebody edits it a bit afterwards as well.

Answer (score 1):

After I have all codes in my machine (i.e, repo sync), it is at mydroid/sdk/monkeyrunner/scripts along with other three:

> help.py  monkey_playback.py  monkey_recorder.py  mr_pydoc.py

Answer (score 1):

This is brilliant answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4470513/551383 but if you really want this file is in android source i.e. http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/sdk/monkeyrunner/scripts/help.py

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in monkeyrunner's help documentation ([monkeyrunner Built-in Help](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html#Help)), you should use parameters in another order:

`monkeyrunner help.py <format> <outfile>`

And don't forget about specifying a full path to the script, if you're running it outside of the `monkeyrunner.bat` directory ([android monkeyrunner scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554576/android-monkey-runner-scripts)).
If you don't have Repo Sync, described by users above, you can find the sources (including `help.py`), for example, here: [monkeyrunner scripts](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/sdk/monkeyrunner/scripts/).

I opened an issue at Google Code ([Issue 26259: monkeyrunner Built-in Help Description Error](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26259)) and I hope that they'll fix it soon.

Comment: yeah monkeyrunner is still brain dead ... Wouldnt work till i ran it from its installation path