# android monkey runner scripts

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, monkey

i am tryig to execute a sample python program through monkey runner command prompt and it is throwing an error

```
Can't open specified script file
Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

    -s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
    -p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
    -v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO,
WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
so any one can guide me how to resolve this one

Answer (score 18):

scriptfile should be a full path file name
try below
`monkeyrunner c:\test_script\first.py`

Comment: Yes, it's really so, because monkeyrunner changes current directory to where it (`monkeyrunner.bat` on Windows) is located, thus looking for the script (`first.py` in your case) in monkeyrunner folder.

Answer (score 1):

try using something like

```
...\tools>monkeyrunner -v ALL first.py
```

where `first.py` was my sample python script which I copied into tools folder of android SDK (the place where `monkeyrunner.bat` is located)

Comment: where i can get these scripts.........i am a beginner to this ....i just need some tutorials for python scripts for running monkey runner

Comment: need some scripts for running monkey runner

Answer (score 1):

Under all unix/linux families OS the sha bang syntax can be used.

Edit the first line of your script with the results of the following command:

```
which monkeyrunner
```

for example, if monkeyrunner (usually provided with android sdk) has been installed under /usr/local/bin/sdk write:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sdk/tools/monkeyrunner
```

or even use "env"

```
#!/usr/bin/env monkeyrunner
```

then set you script file as executable

```
chmod +x <script>
```

You can now launch your script from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

It looks not make sense to switch working directory to Android SDK folder but just for obtain some relative references path for itself. It means you have to specify the full path for your script file and the PNG image files you want to save or compare to.

A better way is modify few lines in the "monkeyrunner.bat" under your SDK folder as below. This will use your current path as working directory, so, no necessary to use full path file name.

```
    rem don't modify the caller's environment
setlocal

rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
set prog=%~f0

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
rem cd /d %~dp0

rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call %~sdp0\lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF

set jarfile=monkeyrunner.jar
set frameworkdir=
set libdir=


if exist %frameworkdir%%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=%~sdp0\lib\

if exist %frameworkdir%%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=%~sdp0\..\framework\

:JarFileOk

set jarpath=%frameworkdir%%jarfile%

if not defined ANDROID_SWT goto QueryArch
    set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%
    goto SwtDone

:QueryArch

    for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar %frameworkdir%archquery.jar') do set swt_path=%frameworkdir%%%a

:SwtDone

if exist %swt_path% goto SetPath
    echo SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
    exit /B

:SetPath

call %java_exe% -Xmx512m -Djava.ext.dirs=%frameworkdir%;%swt_path% -Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir=%frameworkdir%\..\..\platform-tools\ -jar %jarpath% %*
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same things as you did, I resolved by using "monkeyrunner" command under tools, and your script file should be a full path name. It looks like the directory “tools” is the main directory of MonnkeyRunner. I am depressed that I can't run my script files by pydev IDE directly.

Answer (score 0):

monkeyrunner.bat `cygpath -w $(pwd)/monkey.py`